# Can i access my application remotely using a domain name instead of router public ip address?

Tags: networking

I am using port forwarding on zte f660.Problem is i want to access my application remotely using a domain name instead of routers public ip address.Is this possible?Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a static public IP address, you can set any domain name A record to point at it. You could also set the remote machines HOST file to point a domain name at the correct IP.

If you do not, you can sign up for a [DynamicDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) service, such as [DynDNS](http://dyn.com/dns/) or [No-ip](http://www.noip.com).

Comment: My public IP is static.Could you explain how to do this on the router interface?

Comment: Your router interface doesn't need touching - you need to buy a domain from a registrar and use the interface they'll provide to point the domain to your IP address, or edit the HOST file on the remote machine to point `example.com  123.123.123.123`